# Registration Php Script

Tags: php

So I've been Trying to create my Registration PhP from Scratch But I seem to be Having some Trouble. Any Ideas?

```
<?php
```

session_start();

include('../htdocs/connect.php');

if(!empty($_POST)){

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(md5(md5($con, $_POST['password'])));
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password, Email, Active) 
VALUES ('','$user','$pass','$email','')";

$query = mysqli_query($sql);

if($query){
    echo "You have Been Successfully Registered! Welcome to The Community";
}
else{
    echo "I'm sorry. There was a problem with your registration. Please try again later or contact an admin.";
}
```

}
else{

```
echo "Oops. Something Went wrong!";
```

}

?>

EDIT: I edited the Code with your suggestions.

But now it echos that there was a problem with the registration.

Comment: Perhaps you should execute the query instead of testing whether you assigned the string correctly.

Comment: Also, hashing a password with a straight `md5` is barely better than storing it in plain text. Consider using [`password_hash`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email)
VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')";

if(mysqli_query($sql)){
```

As you aren't executing it.

---

Your query is not working because all you are doing is testing if your query string `$sql` is set.

What you want to be doing is running the actual query; which in this case will be harnessing `mysqli_query()` as stated above and checking the response from that.

### Why (*from your comment*)

Basically you're saying:

```
if('SQL STRING IS HERE') {
```

*Which will evaluate to `TRUE`*

instead of actually running the insert query to add the data to the table in your database:

```
if(mysqli_query($sql)) {
```

---

### Notes

As [**`Niels Keurentjes stated in the comments`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279161/registration-php-script/24279204#comment37513123_24279161):

> Also, hashing a password with a straight md5 is barely better than
> storing it in plain text. Consider using [**password_hash**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

---

**EDIT AS PER NEW CODE POSTED.**

That means the `mysqli_query()` returned `false`.

What you want to do is check the error message via `[**mysqli_error()`**][3](https://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.error.php) with something like this:

```
if($sql) {
    echo "Success......";
} else {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

***NOTE:*** Where `$con` is the database connection.

Then post back with the information from that.

Comment: I tried That and You are right. It's not executing the Query. What I'm Trying to Understand Is Why?

Comment: I think it's because your shift key is stuck.

Comment: Saw it. Thanks for the answer. Something still seems to be wrong though. I will update my question with the code I'm using now

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't display anything at all.. @Darren

Answer (score 0):

```
include('../htdocs/connect.php');
```

may be your connect file is not included properly. is there any warning about it?.

or your query may have some error or typo. make sure it is correct.

try putting an echo before the sql statement and copy the query and try to run it in the phpmhyadmin

like this

```
echo $sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email)
VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$email')";
```

Comment: it means your data is not inserted due to a problem in database connectivity or query error.

Comment: Is there anyway I can fix this? My connect.php file should be correct or else it would tell me there was a problem connecting, no?

Comment: I am afraid that your connect.php file is not properly linked in this file. what is your path of connect.php  this file?

Comment: Actually, My bad. I'm sure it's not my connect.php file because I tried copying my connect function into this file and it still doesn;t work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

with `mysqli_real_escape_string` you need to give the database connection as a parameter like: `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['the_post']);`